# Problema de Charset PHP + MYSQL + novo servidor

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, whm

Trabalho com revenda de hospedagens e estou com um problema estranho...

Recentemente adquiri um servidor na ALOG, antes tinha um servidor na hostgator, dai fiz a exportação pelo esquema do cpanel de todas as contas.

Todo site neste servidor tem painel de controle em PHP para alimentar um banco MySQL, os dados cadastrados nesse painel antes da migração, mesmo após a migração apresentam-se perfeitos, caracteres especiais, tudo limpo.

**1º Fato estranho.**

**A)** Uma vez no servidor novo, resolvo cadastrar a palavra "São", ele Salva "São no banco, da pra ver pelo phpMyAdmin.

**B)** No servidor antigo, quando salvo a palavra "São", eu vejo no phpMyAdmin a palavra são dessa maneira : "SÃ£o"

Legal que sempre funcionou assim, quando no frontend do site eu busco no banco, ele me retorna sempre a palavra correta.

Como exportei a conta, todas as configurações de charset dos arquivos de cadastro/arquivos de visualização são iguais, também são iguais as configurações do banco.

Ok, sempre me questionei porque funcionava em da maneira B, mas era feliz porque funcionava.

em meu WHM, o meu `php.ini` esta configurado com charset `iso-8859-1` igual do meu servidor antigo.

**1º Problema:**

mas ai aparece o primeiro problema, as palavras no painel aparecem sem o acentuação correta, por exemplo "Descrição", aparece "DescriÃ§Ã£o", agora como? o charset é o mesmo! o arquivo é o mesmo, o banco foi exportado e importado..

se eu mudo para utf-8, pronto! funciona e aparece certinho, mas ai o server fica diferente a configuração, o novo utf-8, o antigo iso-8859-1, eu vivo com isso, vivo, mas o problema é que tem mais problemas então procuro deixar os 2 iguais pra ir eliminando possibilidades.

**2º Segundo problema:** Esse é estranho...  criei uma pagina, essa pagina esta com a metatag

```
<meta charset="utf-8" >
```

mas o encoding dela esta `iso-8859-1`.
o banco esta como `latin1_swedish_ci` que é `iso-8859-1` certo? a tabela, tudo, exatamente como a configuração do banco do meu antigo server, o que funciona.

Porém quando cadastro palavras, se elas terminam  com caracteres especiais, da problema

por exemplo a frase  "é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião" quando salvo, ela salva "é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião" no banco e na hora de mostrar ela mostra "é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião"

mas se coloco algum caracter especial no final, tipo "reuniã" ele me some com o ultimo caracter e não mostra nada!

mas se eu coloco 2 caracteres especiais, ai ele obedece, tipo "reuíã" ai ele mostra. da pra entender? se eu posto o somente a letra "É" não funciona, se eu posto "ÉÉ" funciona!!

se não acredita, da uma olhada http://www.heytec.com.br/teste/

---

E isso foi o máximo que eu consegui, porque mesmo sabendo que essa configuração estava correta pois funciona no outro servidor, eu mudei e diz todas as combinações possíveis.

tinha hora que me retornava "??" e coisas piores, esse foi o mais longe que cheguei!

Alguma alma caridosa pode me dar uma luz?? to sem dormir a 2 dias por causa disso.

PESQUISA FEITA DIRETO NO PUTTY NO BANCO DE DADOS - SERVIDOR NOVO

```
                             |
-> +----+----------------------------------------------+
-> |  1 |                                              |
-> |  2 | 1                                            |
-> |  3 | é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião       |
-> |  4 | é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião       |
-> |  5 | é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião       |
-> |  6 | é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião       |
-> |  7 | é maçaa ó dados, ã, implícito, reunião       |
-> |  8 | Acentuação 123                               |
-> |  9 | Acentuação 456                               |
-> +----+----------------------------------------------+
-> 9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

PESQUISA FEITA DIRETA NO BANCO DE DADOS, SERVIDOR ANTIGO

```
 select * from dados;
+----+-----------+
| id | valor     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ma&#231;a |
|  2 | ol&#225;  |
|  3 | teste     |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Um detalhe que esqueci de mencionar, é que se resgato a variável por POST, ela já da problema, e se coloco o caracter especial direto na query, ele funciona, o problema esta no resgate dela em PHP, agora porque eu não sei, apache? config no `php.ini`?

Voltei agora o `php.ini` como utf8, para que eu possa ter os dados que já foram cadastrados em ordem.

assim fica minha tela do ambiente de teste

```
"� ma�aa � dados, �, impl�cito, reuni�o"
```

---------------------- CONFIG PHP SERVIDOR NOVO

www.heytec.com.br / teste/ teste.php

---------------------- CONFIG PHP SERVIDOR ANTIGO

162.144.115.36 / ~heytecco / teste/

Comment: DescriÃ§Ã£o significa que o dado está gravado no BD como utf-8 mas sendo mostrado em iso-8859-1, OU está passando por 2 codificações UTF-8 por engano. Veja os dados em binário na base de dados, e acrescente na pergunta para termos certeza (pode ser convertendo para hexadecimal).

Comment: Fiz seu teste e tá tudo certo aqui com a acentuação. http://i.stack.imgur.com/z5bIx.png - Grande chance do BD estar em UTF-8 mesmo, e por exibir em iso, nao sai certo.

Comment: teste colocando apenas um caracter especial, tipo É, ou colocando apenas um na frase toda e ele no final!

Comment: Pra começar, vc está misturando uma página UTF-8 com um form iso, qual a idéia? Me parece que você está tentando resolver por tentativa e erro. Se é pra testar, pode experimentar por UTF-8 em tudo e exibir os dados antigos do banco para ver se sai certo. Além disso, precisa testar tudo sem utf8 encode/decode no PHP, senão vira uma loucura. Charset é uma coisa BEM simples, o problema é que pouca gente gasta tempo pra entender, e por isso vemos problemas com isso toda hora.

Comment: Justamente, estou na tentativa e erro, ja deixei tudo em UTF-8, ja deixei tudo em ISO, ja mesclei os 2, essa ai foi a config que mais cheguei perto da solução, se eu deixo o php.ini em utf8 ele nao me da problema na exibição dos dados antigos, mas a config padrao é iso no server antigo, nao estou entendendo nada.!

Comment: Misto sempre vai dar problema. O importante é você detectar como os dados estão. O melhor seria ver os bytes, aí teria certeza absoluta. Tudo indica que é UTF-8, mas só analisando os bytes numericamente em vez de jogando na tela.

Comment: Amigo Danilo aconselho-o a instalar um corretor automático, para corrigir os erros do seu texto.

Comment: @Danilo, tire urgente seu form do ar, tá completamente aberto pra fazer SQL injection. Jajá algum engraçadinho apaga seu BD todo.

Comment: é um BD teste, em uma conta teste, nao tem nada nele, é soh pra tentar resolver o problema, obrigado pela preocupação!

Comment: Para a página de teste configure a comunicação com o banco como utf-8, eu não sei bem que extensão do PHP você esta usando, mas aqui tem um jeito de fazer isso: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-set-charset.php e por favor, salve o documento como utf-8 também, ou crei um novo.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php nessa página tem informações de como você configurar o charset para outras páginas. mas ainda sim, fazer isso funcionar na página de teste é diferente de fazer funcionar no sistema.

Comment: Quando faço isso, seto essas configs de charset, o erro passa para ??? ma???aa ??? dados, ???, impl???cito, reuni???o, eu ja havia feito estes testes, refiz eles agora por via das duvidas, tb criei um novo arquivo utf8 para teste, nada...

Tem uma coisa, quando envio a partir e um form, uma palavra tipo "maça" por post,  e dou um echo $_POST[campo] ele ja me retorna com problema, sem mesmo inserir no bd

Comment: talvez seja algo com o servidor mesmo. se você da o post e o caracter já vem indecifravel hehe.   veja se a solução desse link resolve http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27230

Comment: Vou testar amigo, ja respondo, obrigado!

Comment: Amigo, sabe como posso fazer isso no WHM??

Comment: Consegui fazer a alteração direto pelo SSH, porém nao obtive sucesso, testei todas as opções citadas no forum apresentado. =[ acho q vou voltar pro servidor antigo.. q zica..

Comment: você reiníciou o apache?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você criou o novo banco de dados com o charset errado, e as tabelas desse banco de dados estão herdando esse novo charset.

Veja qual é o charset do seu banco de dados velho e configure o novo com ele.

Isso não explica o porquê dos valores do banco estarem sendo gravados como entidades html, mas  não custa tentar.

Comment: Ambos os bancos estão latin1, o banco, as tabelas, os fields, acho que nao deve ser no banco o problema, pq quando resgato por post os dados, eles voltam com problema, mesmo sem inserir no banco! =/

Comment: CesarMiguel é respota bem clara é que deve ser o charset dos bancos que está desconfigurado, se a resposta está errada é outra história.

Comment: Eu tive esse problema há alguns meses com o phpMyAdmin. Eu coloquei as configurações padrão em utf8_general_ci assim que eu estava criando as tabelas sem se preocupar com as definições.
Um dia, eu comecei a ter problemas em uma nova tabela. Eu então percebi que PhpMyAdmin tinha mudado a configuração padrão, tornou-se latin1_swedish_ci! 
Então eu mudei o char-set para voltar em utf8, a configuração padrão no utf8_general_ci e está tudo em ordem novamente.
Então veja a sua configuração padrão no PhpMyAdmin porque é possível que ela impõe um valor que não é o que você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Já passei pelo mesmo problema.

Mantenha esta tag no seu html:

`<meta charset="utf-8" >`

E no PHP, use a função utf8_encode().

Exemplo, considerando que a $variavel veio de um SELECT:

`utf8_encode($variavel);`

Isso normaliza os acentos e tira os  do html.